# IE, ajax & "no transport" : $.support.cors = true not working either

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

You know the drill...Firefox and Chrome are fine. IE is raising my blood pressure :)

I've done plenty of searching and 90% of what I read says that adding `$.support.cos = true;` just prior to the `$.ajax` request should fix the IE cross-domain issue.

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm still getting "no transport". So here I am looking for any other suggestions, insights, etc.

Comment: Can we see the code in question? Gotta make sure you're doing it right.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/tlianza/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js which is required in IE see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283